# Setting gcp alert for particular time window

Tags: google-cloud-platform, time, monitoring, alerts

In Gcp monitoring, is it possible to set up the alert to trigger only within a certain timeframe. For instance, we have some alerts for a cron job that triggers in the morning and we only want to trigger the cloud monitoring cron job alerts in that morning timeframe. Let me know if any one is aware about it.

Checked the google documentation and it seems they don't support time duration based metric.

Comment: did you end up finding the answer? wondering the same... or if there is a possibility to trigger a logs based check once every one hour, to not constantly check for no reason.